# Getting application path

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get my project path at the root. I have been unable to do so, I have tried:

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

But this goes to deep, how do I just get the path to the project root?

I am using C# with .NET framework 4.0.

Comment: Are you planning to ship your project along with the .exe?  Copy the resources you need.

Comment: This isn't worded very clearly, so I'm taking a guess about what you mean by "this goes to deep" and deciphering your comments on the answers.  Please correct me if I misunderstand.  Are you trying to get the path to the .csproj file, or to the exe that's created when you compile?  And are you trying to do this within your application, or within Visual Studio? Actually, it would be just really helpful if you were to just post the path you ARE getting and then the path that you WANT to get.

Comment: can't you just use `System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "..", "..")` - I realise that this will not suit every situation.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.
```

Comment: It also returns the exe file location with filename.exe in the end

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Comment: It also returns the exe file location

Comment: Yes. In the end of output it says Bin/Release

Answer (score 0):

From [Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx) you can get, at least, the command line

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the below:

```
String assemblyFileName = typeof(Class1).Assembly.CodeBase.Replace("file:///", "");
FileInfo assemblyInfo = new FileInfo(assemblyFileName);
Console.WriteLine(assemblyInfo.Directory);
```

NOTE: Class1 is a class in the library you are executing from